# zsh: command not found error even after installing packages

Tags: python, import, zsh

I am trying to import libraries into visual studio code but keep encountering the error "zsh: command not found: import".

The packages have been installed in the terminal via "pip3 install pymysql sqlalchemy pandas'. But the error keeps popping out whenever I use the import command in the IDE.

In my terminal, I have also exited the REPL (i.e >>>) environment and used my own hostname as the working environment.

Comment: I don't know pip3, but did you verify that the commands are in your [PATH](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-path-environment-variable)? Can you invoke them by providing an absolute path explicitly?

Comment: i used 'which import' in the terminal , and it returns 'import not found'. do you know how do i go about installing it ?

Comment: Well, this suggests that your PATH is wrong, although a manual inspection (or at least doing a `rehash`) would not harm. Did you actually **read** the wepage I linked to in my comment? It contains everything you need to know about _PATH_; and, honestly, you can't do any serious work without understanding the PATH-concept (in Linux, Mac, Windows, ...), so please study this topic carefully.